# How to update my current directory while looping over it in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, aix

So, i loop over the command "ls"

```
    for d in $(ls)
    do
      echo $d
      rm -rf f1*.txt
    done
```

**Before Loop:** ls has [ f1.txt f2.txt f5.txt f11.txt f12.txt f7.txt ]

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**
f1.txt f2.txt f5.txt f7.txt

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**
f1.txt f2.txt f5.txt f11.txt f12.txt f7.txt

**After Loop:** ls has [ f2.txt f5.txt f7.txt ]

It is not updating the command which is updating. Kindly help as I just started with Shell script and this is my first script for my job.

Comment: The `$(ls)` (to which you should prefer a simple `*` in the context of a for loop) is only interpreted once at the start of the loop. You could obtain the same behaviour but your desired output with the following code : `rm -rf f1*.txt; ls`

Comment: Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Yes, in the actual problem I do need the loop, and specific files  of same pattern get removed after doing some work on it. So, if there could be any way to do this.

Comment: @Aaron I really need it to work with the loop.

Comment: `for d in *; do test -f "$d" || continue; DoSomething "$d"; done`

Comment: Maybe `for f in f[0-9].txt; do echo "$f"; [[ $f = f1*.txt ]] && rm -f "$f"; done`. It sounds like a weird assignment anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need to keep an list of the files in a place that can be updated as you iterate over that list. One possible way of doing this is to have an associative array, keyed by filename, with the value of each element being a flag indicating whether , or not, it is active. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A files=()

for file in *; do
  files["${file}"]=1
done

for file in "${!files[@]}"; do    # Iterate over the keys
  if [ files["${file}"] -eq 1 ]; then
    echo ${file}
    for f in f1*.txt; do
      rm "${f}"
      entries["${f}"]=0
    done
  fi
done
```